# QThread blocks the event loop

Tags: qt, qthread

I've just recently started working wtih QThreads API and faced an odd issue.

I have created a subclass of QThread with reimplemented run() method
Here it is:

```
void ThreadChecker::run()
{
    emit TotalDbSize(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        QString number;
        number.setNum(i);
        number.append("\n");
        emit SimpleMessage(number);
        //pausing is necessary, since in the real program the thread will perform quite lenghty tasks
        usleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Here is the code that calls this thread:

```
ThreadChecker thread;


connect(&thread, SIGNAL(TotalDbSize(int)), this, SLOT(SetMaximumProgress(int)));
//This slot writes the message into the QTextEdit
connect(&thread, SIGNAL(SimpleMessage(QString)), this, SLOT(ProcessSimpleMessage(QString)));

thread.start();
```

The way I intend this to work is for the QTextEdit to update every 10 milliseconds. But instead the program just lags for 10 seconds and then all the signals rush at once. Moreso, while the program lags, it behaves like the event loop is blocked (buttons won't [ress, the resizing doesn't work etc)

What am I missing here?

Comment: try to add the following to your `ThreadChecker` ctor: `moveToThread(this)`. Note, however, that's **NOT** a solution. It is just to check if it helps, to better understand your problem.

Comment: If by ctor you mean constructor, then it didn't fix the issue

Comment: Why don't you simply use QTimer?

Comment: As it's stated in the comments, I use pause, since in the original program is intended to calculate large chunks of data, effectively freezing the progress through function

Comment: I see only one explanation of this behavior. I suspecting that last section of code is in code branch which does not contain execution of event loop, so destructor of thread blocks (invokes waitFor) your main thread until your jobs finishes. When you used code from ixSci probably you have changed that and event look is run before destructor of thread is invoked. Anyway ixScis code is correct your can lead to some bugs.

Comment: @MarekR, QThread dtor doesn't block.

Comment: @ixSci Ok you are right, it only [prompts a warrning](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/0aca5cf05288dc4d2175d1c4a78bf62a5ea96b21:src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp#L400), still I'm curious why his main thread blocks until job is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
class Updater: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void updateLoop()
    {
        emit TotalDbSize(1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            QString number;
            number.setNum(i);
            number.append("\n");
            emit SimpleMessage(number);
            //pausing is necessary, since in the real program the thread will perform quite lenghty tasks
            usleep(10000);
        }
    }
signals:
    void TotalDbSize(...);
    void SimpleMessage(...);

};
...
QThread updaterThread;
Updater updater;
updater.moveToThread(&updaterThread);
connect(&updater, SIGNAL(TotalDbSize(int)), this, SLOT(SetMaximumProgress(int)));
//This slot writes the message into the QTextEdit
connect(&updater, SIGNAL(SimpleMessage(QString)), this, SLOT(ProcessSimpleMessage(QString)));
connect(&updaterThread, SIGNAL(started()), &updater, SLOT(updateLoop()));
updaterThread.start();
```

I didn't check it, though. Note that you should guarantee that `updaterThread` and `updater` don't get out of scope.

======

Why code from the question doesn't work? I can only guess: you have your signals attached to the QThread object and when you do `connect` you have a direct connection since `thread` and `this` are in the same thread. So when you emit signal direct connection works and you update your TextBox from outside the GUI thread which is wrong and may cause any result. Note, however, that my guess may be wrong and exact cause could be found with debugger.

Also read the [Threads, Events and QObjects](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects) article. It is a great article to grasp of how to use threads in Qt right.

Comment: I tried that, and it works like a charm. Thanks. Now I'm just curiuos why didn't my original code work as intended? from what I gathered, subclassing QThread is outdated and counter to OOP principles, but not wrong

Comment: @WereWind, unless you want to change how threads are controlled, subclassing QThread is wrong; http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: You'll also find this useful: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: @WereWind `unless you want to change how threads are controlled, subclassing QThread is wrong`, or is it? See [this](http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html) and [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details).

Comment: @thuga, I believe the post in Woboq is just wrong. Thread is not Qt invention and in other places(at least those I know about) no one subclassing threads. You should move work to thread and not subclass it. Thread is OS primitive why anyone should want to subclass it? Moreover when you see something like this: `connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));` you should rise an alarm. It is C++ and you'd better have C++-like object life time mechanisms. I believe `deleteLater()` should be used in extremely rare cases.

Comment: @ixSci So the Qt documentation is wrong again? `in other places(at least those I know about) no one subclassing threads`. What do you mean by `other places`? They do exactly that in Java.

Comment: @thuga, yes Qt documentation wrong in the sense of proposing wrong usage. I'm not familiar with Java I'm from C++ world, also I didn't see anything like that in C#, though I'm not very familiar with it. Subclassing thread to create a "worker" like OP Text box updater, for example, violates OOP inheritance "is" principle. So, yes, it is a wrong way of doing things. Even if Qt devs don't consider it like this.